# Mapping multiple table from one pojo

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping, rdbms

[image]

I want to Map Shipping and Retail Store table from Product table using XML approach of Hibernate. I have able to map Product and retail store using one to many relationship where key is ProductId now I want to map shipping table using one to one relationship in the product . I have tried

```
1. <one-to-one name="shippingDetail" class="com.to.Shipping"></one-to-one>

2. <many-to-one name="shippingDetail" class="com.to.Shipping"
        cascade="all" unique="true"> </many-to-one>

3.  <one-to-one name="shippingDetail" constrained="true"> </one-to-one>

4.  <one-to-one name="shippingDetail" cascade="all"/>
```

But not working please help me thanks in advance..........

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code. which helps you.

add mapping in your shipping xml config file.

```
<one-to-one name="product" class="....Product" constrained="true"></one-to-one>
```